# Почему вылазит tunnel server offline при запуске Gulp

Tags: gulp

Сама проблема

```
PS D:\uniphantcode\NZcompare\money-compare\money-compare> gulp
[15:32:36] Using gulpfile D:\uniphantcode\NZcompare\money-compare\money-compare\gulpfile.js
[15:32:36] Starting 'libs:build'...
[15:32:36] Starting 'html:build'...
[15:32:36] Starting 'css:build'...
[15:32:36] Starting 'js:build'...
[15:32:36] Starting 'fonts:build'...
[15:32:36] Starting 'img:build'...
[15:32:36] Starting 'watch'...
[15:32:36] Finished 'watch' after 6.5 ms
[15:32:36] Starting 'webserver'...
[15:32:36] Finished 'webserver' after 14 ms
[15:32:36] Finished 'libs:build' after 74 ms
[15:32:36] Finished 'fonts:build' after 63 ms
[15:32:36] gulp-imagemin: Minified 0 images
[15:32:36] Finished 'img:build' after 66 ms
[15:32:37] Finished 'js:build' after 167 ms
[15:32:37] Finished 'html:build' after 238 ms
[15:32:37] Finished 'css:build' after 236 ms
[15:32:37] Starting 'build'...
[15:32:37] Finished 'build' after 28 μs
[15:32:37] Starting 'default'...
[15:32:37] Finished 'default' after 3.07 μs
tunnel server offline: connect ECONNREFUSED 138.197.63.247:443, retry 1s
tunnel server offline: connect ECONNREFUSED 138.197.63.247:443, retry 1s
tunnel server offline: connect ECONNREFUSED 138.197.63.247:443, retry 1s
```

Вчера работал с этим проектом и подобрых проблем небыло, что может быть? Комп со вчера был выключен и ничего на нем не делалось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел временное решение, не знаю правильное или нет:

```
gulp.task('webserver', function () {
browserSync({
  server: { baseDir: "./dist" },
  tunnel: false,
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 8080,
  open: true,
  logLevel: "silent",
  notify: false,
  logLevel: "info"
});
});
```

Я заменил `tunnel: true,` на `false`

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся сегодня с такой же проблемой. Заменил browser-sync на gulp-webserver

Comment: Дайте пожалуйста более развёрнутый ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Тоже заменил tunnel: true, на false, заработало.
Для информации прикладываю версии:

- gulp: 3.9.1,
- nodejs: 10x,
- "browser-sync": "~2.26.5"